# ROW_NUMBER Alternative for SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000

RIGHT now I'm using ROW_NUMBER() in my procedure in SQL Server 2008 as follows:

```
WITH cars as(SELECT carid,mileage,retailprice,imageurl,model,year, 
             Zips.Distance AS Miles, Manufacturers.mfgName as Make,
             dealers.companyname as companyname, CASE @sortby 
WHEN 'D' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  Manufacturers.mfgName) 
WHEN 'P' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY retailprice) 
WHEN 'M' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY mileage) 
END as 'rownum'
FROM usedcars INNER JOIN #TempZips Zips ON Zips.ZipCode =usedcars.loczip
left join Manufacturers on Manufacturers.mfgid=usedcars.mfgid 
left join dealers on dealers.dealerid = usedcars.dealerid 
where usedcars.active=1 and usedcars.dealerid=@dealerid)
select @totalrecords as totalrec,*  from cars 
where rownum between @skip and  @take
```

Is there an equivalent to this that works in SQL2000? (ROW_NUMBER wasn't introduced until SQL2005).

Comment: Why did you develop it in SQL Server 2008? This is so awkward in SQL Server 2000.

Comment: If SQL 2000 was going to be the minimum supported db, then all development should have occurred in SQL 2000 to prevent this situation where a feature in a later product is "accidentally" used. My suggestion would be to recommend that the client upgrade to SQL 2005 or later as the amount of effort to retrofit the solution to work in SQL 2000, will be more than the upgrade cost.

Comment: I completely understand. This is something our client purchased and they dont want to upgrade to sql server 2008 or 2005

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a temp table with an identity column, and insert your data into that.

Then use the temp table.

Comment: See MS KB http://support.microsoft.com/kb/186133/en-us for some examples of this.