# EF4 & SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I've developed my website using EF4 and SQL Server 2005, but when moving to the staging site it turns out that they use SQL Server 2000.

Now I'm getting this error, which I believe is related to SQL Server 2000:

```
Incorrect syntax near '('. 'row_number' is not a recognized function name.
```

Is there a way of fixing this?

Thanks

Comment: Could you give us more information regarding the query you are running so that we could try to come up with an alternative query that doesn't make use of row_number function?

Comment: it's EF4 that creates the query...

Comment: I just did the same thing, and was about to ask the same question.  Now I'm looking at having to re-code my data layer entirely.

Comment: Having exactly the same issue, I hope there is a work around somewhere. Looking at a lot of re-writing otherwise. The problem is, the development machine had SQL Server 2005 express and I only just realised the problem at the time of publish! *sigh*

Comment: no workaround - I had to go for a SQL Server upgrade

Comment: Open your .edmx in as XML and set `ProviderManifestToken="2000"`. Thats all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EF v4 does not support SQL Server 2000. More details here:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/499186/entity-framework-v2-doesn-t-support-sql-2000

Comment: Doesn't support = no way around that.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600630/entity-framework-v2-doesnt-support-sql-2000 for more details

Comment: @user441365: no - EF 4, EF 4.1 do **not** support SQL Server 2000 - not now, not **EVER** - SQL Server 2000 is dead technology - time to upgrade! (heck: the regular support for SQL Server **2005** is running out **this month!**)

Comment: unfortunately is not my choice to upgrade SQL Server... What other alternatives do I have?

Comment: @user441365: use an ORM that supports SQL Server 2000 - e.g. [XPO](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/ORM/Info.xml), [CoolStorage](http://www.findbestopensource.com/product/coolstorage), or one of the many others (Google or Bing will help you)

Comment: maybe downgrade to EF1? but this means going down to .net 3.5 doesn't it?

Comment: I would try to convince the business/your client to upgrade to SQL 2008 (2005 at **least**). Microsoft has officially stopped supporting SQL 2000 (although they might offer [extended support](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?LN=en-za&x=13&y=11&p1=2852)). We recently had to upgrade all our servers to SQL2008 (from 2000). It was well worth the effort.

Comment: @tobias86: regular support for SQL Server 2005 is expiring **this month** - so if you upgrade, go to 2008 or 2008 R2 - anything else makes no sense, really...

Comment: @marc_s: Well there you go :) I'm a big fan of R2.

Comment: I read on another post that there is some sort of workaround: "What happens if you generate model with VS 2008 and then convert that project to VS2010 and change target framework to .Net 4.0?" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600630/entity-framework-v2-doesnt-support-sql-2000

Comment: @user, I did all my development in VS2008, and I'm having the same problem.  I don't think the choice of IDE is the main problem.  It's EF. I am probably going to try and rebuild my model against a 2000 virtual instance I have, but if that doesn't work (and it probably won't, from the sound of things) then I most likely will go back and re-code the data layer by hand.  I don't have any time, this thing has to be delivered pronto.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the exact same problem and as per the comments/responses on StackOverflow I had almost given up and flicked it to client to upgrade their database to > 2000 version. Unfortunately that wasn't possible for them due to many other issues. I had to go around googling for a solution and from somewhere I found a work-around.

This is what I did.

- Right clicked the ModelName.EDMX file -> Open With
- Selected XML (Text) Editor
- Found ProviderManifestToken="2005" and replaced it with
  ProviderManifestToken="2000"
- Published the changes and voila!

Now the reason I'm saying it's a work-around (not a solution) is because

1. If you update your model from database again and your development
   machine database is >= 2000 (which is likely to be a case as SQL
   2000 connection is not supported at all by MS according to [this
   article](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/499186/entity-framework-v2-doesn-t-support-sql-2000)) this value in the XML will change automatically
2. Also, the queries generated by EF after this change have worked in
   my situation but I cannot guarantee that all the queries ever
   generated by your application would work without any problems

Answer (score 0):

Row_Number() returns the sequential number for a each row returned. Are you calling Row_number(), or is the entity framework?

Either way, you may be able to write a user-defined function that re-implements ROW_NUMBER. Stackoverflow post on this here:
[ROW_NUMBER Alternative for SQL Server 2000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064788/row-number-alternative-for-sql-server-2000)

Not sure this is going to do any good in the long run; you're likely to find that you get around this problem only to encounter the next reason that EF doesn't work on SQL 2000. But, it might be worth the few minutes to try.

Comment: it's EF4 that creates the query