# How do write the following sql fragment for SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server-2000

Can Someone please help to how to write the below code in SQL Server2000? Thanks

```
 WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT *, 
                ( Row_number() OVER(ORDER BY productid, transactionid, 
                  statusdate 
                  DESC) 
                   )AS 
                rownum 
         FROM   @table), 
     cte2 
     AS (SELECT cte.*, 
                ( CASE 
                    WHEN cte.status = Isnull((SELECT t.status 
                                              FROM   cte t 
                                              WHERE  t.rownum = ( cte.rownum + 1 
                                                                )), 
                                      '') 
                  THEN 1 
                    ELSE 0 
                  END )AS rownum2 
         FROM   cte) 
SELECT cte2.productid, 
       cte2.transactionid, 
       cte2.details, 
       cte2.status, 
       cte2.statusdate, 
       cte2.requestdate 
FROM   cte2 
WHERE  rownum2 = 0
```

Comment: Also what is the reference to 2005 about ? is that where this code is from?  Please take some time to explain and you'll get much better answers

Comment: SQL Server 2005 has an OVER() function which is not available in 2000. This SQL would not run in SQL Server 2000.

Comment: Update this question with the sample data and table definition from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875247/convert-sql-server-2005-to-2000

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could add a description of what the query does.

Answer (score 2):

[DigbySwift's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874929/sql-server-2005-to-2000/7875040#7875040) mentions that there is a problem with ROW_NUMBER and you need to solve that first. You can use the idea in his answer, and you could also look at answers to similar questions such as these:

- [ROW_NUMBER Alternative for SQL Server 2000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064788/row-number-alternative-for-sql-server-2000)
- [Row_Number simulation in Sql server 2000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490336/row-number-simulation-in-sql-server-2000)

However there's also another problem: SQL Server 2000 doesn't support CTEs (`WITH ... AS ...`).

To solve this use subselects instead of CTEs by removing the `WITH` clause and moving the definition of the CTE to the place(s) where it is used.

For example this query using CTEs:

```
WITH T1 AS (SELECT a,b,c FROM ...)
SELECT * FROM T1
```

Becomes:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT a,b,c FROM ...
) AS T1
```

Hopefully that is enough to get you started.

Comment: Also I think Row_Number() function is also not defined in 2000, Here is my complete Query

Comment: I have linked complete query to convert.. Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

There is no OVER() function in 2000, so you will need to re-address/move the initial cte select. You already have a table variable @table, so I would modify this to include the row numbers, by adding a identity column.

You could then use a subquery to extract what you need from cte2.